# Height Blend Mask and Vertex color based Material Blending Shader

Tags: shaders

Im trying to texture a building and I want to mix diferent textures of bricks, damage and all, I´m combining them using vertex paint as a mask but.... Does anyone knows how can I make a heightblend like shader to mix two different materials based on their heightmap and vertex color (like in Substance Designer Heightblend). I want to paint a vertex color mask that is also tweaked by the height of both materials so the textures don´t blend in a gradient but in a more realistic way. If anyone knows where I could find info about this....  Thank you!:blush:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the height map on your blending gradient (I use vertex colour, but you can also take a UV channel or just use a image texture), you just need to run it through a Smoothstep node like so:

[image: Blending a Vertex Colour channel and a Smoothstep node]

[image: The resulting blend using textures form BlenderKit]

The vertex colour is the gradient, I run it through a smooth step node. Edge 0 is the height map, edge 1 controls how harsh/soft the blending is. Use the result as the factor to blend your shaders or textures!

This is loosely based of of the documentation for Unity Shaderforge an old unity plugin: http://acegikmo.com/shaderforge/wiki/index.php?title=Advanced_Texture_Splatting

Comment: Thank you! I Have to try this !